# Show igraph plots in Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, igraph

I am trying to plot `igraph` plots in Google Colab and cannot get it to work.

I am using the following code to plot a graph:

```
fg = Graph.Full(n=40, directed=False, loops=False)
plot(fg).show()
```

At first I got this error `"NotImplementedError: showing plots is not implemented on this platform: Linux"` but I was able to get around it by configuring the image viewer using the following:

```
from igraph import Configuration
cfg = Configuration.instance()
cfg['apps.image_viewer'] = "eog"
```

This removed the error but still, no image is being displayed.
Removing the `show()` statement to have it displayed inline does not work either.

Is there a way to plot igraph graphs in Google Colab or is it simply not compatible?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you install `pycairo` on Google Colabs? If so, single `plot(fg)` should work.

Comment: You can do the following: `!apt install libcairo2-dev` and `!pip install pycairo` to install `pycairo` on Google Colab.

Comment: @mathfux Why  don't you make that an answer?

Comment: @Szabolcs Not sure if it helps for OP. It behaves a little bit different for me. `plot(fg).show()` won't work but `plot(fg)` does. Also, not sure if it's `pycairo` related problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.show()` method is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. Do not use it. See the docstring for more information. Simply use `plot(g)`.

---

You can install igraph on Google Colab using

```
!pip install igraph
```

To use plotting, you have two options.

With the Cairo backend:

Install `pycairo`,

```
!apt install libcairo2-dev
!pip install pycairo
```

```
import igraph as ig
g = ig.Graph.Erdos_Renyi(n=100, m=200)
ig.plot(g)
```

With the experimental matplotlib backend (not yet feature-complete):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ig.plot(g, target=ax)
```

Or shorter:

```
ig.plot(g, target=plt.axes())
```

[image]

Comment: `igraph` has a support for `matplotlib`, wow! Nice to hear from you it's developing fast.